# ARM Cortex A9 second execution unit

Tags: arm, cortex-a

I am trying to understand the full working of execution stage in ARM cortex A9 and the types of instructions that are executed in second execution unit(ALU).  Till now i was able to find quite limited references that were not much helpful. If any of you know anything related to execution in "Second execution unit of ARM cortex A9" or any related references, please let me know!! Also it is possible to discuss further here in the forum directly. Looking forward to your input.

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not the right place for queries like this, this community expects you to ask a particular technical question and get an answer (if you're lucky). Your "question" is more like an attempt to start a discussion..

Have a look here:
https://community.arm.com/content?query=cortex-a9

And, of course, there are tons of documents on www.arm.com